Detection of exception type in HttpClient sendAsync method
I'm trying to determine what exception I got, but all exceptions are of type System.AggregateException and unimportant - SSL validation failed and host is unreachable.
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage {
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://mydomain.ru"), 
};

try {
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;

    return ((int) httpResponseMessage.StatusCode, httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
} catch (System.Exception e) {
   // e.GetType() always return `System.AggregateException`
   return (500, $"{e.Message}; Error type: `{e.GetType().ToString()}`); 
}

Exist some way for detect what is the error?

look at the InnerExceptions of the AggregateException

HttpClient package work with platform implementation it's produce specific exception on error on different platforms.
For adequate processed exception need to use compile-condition blocks for needed platform (in this code is iOS and Android).
On Android AggregateException has in InnerException a differents exceptions, iOS use code property for indicate exception types
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage {
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://mydomain.ru"), 
};

try {
    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;

    return ((int) httpResponseMessage.StatusCode, httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
} catch (System.Exception e) {
    String errorMessage = "UNKNOWN CRITICAL ERROR";
    if (e is not System.AggregateException) {
        errorMessage = $"{e.Message}; Error type: `{e.GetType().ToString()}`";
    } else {
        ((AggregateException) e).Handle((x) => {
#if ANDROID
            if (e.InnerException?.InnerException is Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException) {
                errorMessage = "SSL validation error";
            } else if (e.InnerException?.InnerException is Java.Net.ConnectException) {
                errorMessage = "Unreachable host, check Internet connection";
            }
#elif IOS
            if (e.InnerException?.InnerException is Foundation.NSErrorException) {
                if (((Foundation.NSErrorException) e.InnerException?.InnerException)?.Code == -1202) {
                    errorMessage = "SSL validation error";
                } else if (((Foundation.NSErrorException) e.InnerException?.InnerException)?.Code == -1009) {
                    errorMessage = "Unreachable host, check Internet connection";
                }
            }
#endif

                return true;
        });
    }


   // e.GetType() always return `System.AggregateException`
   return (500, errorMessage); 
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
